# Splash color is not visible while I am using it in my Custom ModalBottomSheet

Tags: flutter

I am not getting splash effect when my Inkwell is inside showModalBottomsheet while it is customized, I wanted the rounded corners, so I hide the background color to transparent, when the background color is in white, the splash effect works fine. I tried playing with Alpha and Opacity properties, but no luck there.

````
    questionEditAndDelete(BuildContext context) {
    return showModalBottomSheet(
        context: context,
        elevation: 0,
        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
        builder: (context) {
          return Container(
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.15,
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.white,
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                  topRight: Radius.circular(25), topLeft: Radius.circular(25)),
            ),
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                children: [
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom:20.0),
                    child: Divider(
                      indent: 110,
                      endIndent: 110,
                      thickness: 4,
                      color: Colors.grey,
                    ),
                  ),
              InkWell(
                onTap: (){},
                splashColor: Colors.grey,
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(15)),
                child: Container(
                  height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height*0.05,
                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                  child: Row(
                    children: [
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal:4.0),
                        child: Icon(EvaIcons.editOutline, size: 26,),
                      ),
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal:2.0),
                        child: Text('Edit', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18),),
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
                  InkWell(
                    onTap: (){},
                    splashColor: Colors.grey,
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(15)),
                    child: Container(
                      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height*0.05,
                      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                      child: Row(
                        children: [
                          Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal:4.0),
                            child: Icon(Icons.delete_outline_outlined, size: 26,),
                          ),
                          Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal:2.0),
                            child: Text('Delete', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18),),
                          )
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
            ]),
          );
        });
  }```
````

Comment: check https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/InkWell-class.html and read `Troubleshooting` section

Answer (score 0):

Yes you are right so available alternate options are

1. Replace InkWell with Gesture Detector
2. Remove splash color of InkWell or set splash color to Colors.Transparent

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but couldn't resolve the issue :/